# Should I use <td> or <div> with nested <div> to contain thumbnails

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project, an ordering website for a client. I'm not a designer but what I usually do is use bootstrap and modify it based on my needs. Usually, I do the backend and some design.

There is already a prepared design for home page which I will structure in html/css.

I have a simple question for designers. Is it **better** to use `<div>`s with nested  tags or use `<td>`s to contain images and other elements in the design screenshot below?

[image]

I know there are good reasons and pros and cons for every tag you decide to use. I just thought it would be better to ask.

I'd appreciate any comment or answer to this.

Comment: Neither. That's a list. You use a `<ul>` and each image is a `<li>`. You do NOT, ever. use `<tables>` and `<td>`s for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use divs as they can be made responsive.

Tables are cumbersome and non-responsive.

I highly suggest using Bootstrap framework for such purpose.

https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/thumbnail-gallery/

https://mobirise.com/bootstrap-gallery/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap then it's good to have div managed with class like row and col-md. It is always suggested to avoid table for such kind of thing. With bootstrap you can easily manage this. You can [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) link.